# Hidden field not updating sqllite table in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

im a noob with rails and I cant understand why a hidden field that i have in a form is not updating in the table.  My form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@cricket_club_advert) do |f| %>
  <% current_user_id = current_user.id %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "user_id", current_user_id %>

<% if @cricket_club_advert.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@cricket_club_advert.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this cricket_club_advert from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @cricket_club_advert.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>


  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">

      <%= f.label "Title" %>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <%= f.label "Type of Player Required" %>
      <%= f.text_field :player_type %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have added the field user_id to the accepted params, this can be seen here:

```
def cricket_club_advert_params
  params[:cricket_club_advert].permit(:user_id, :title, :player_type, :description, :airfares, :accomadation, :job, :incentives)
end
```

However, when ever i create or edit a new record the field does not get updated and no errors are created.

If I make the field in the form a text_field with the id user_id it works fine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION TO THE ERROR**

The error is that you are using `form_for` but calling the `hidden_field_tag` instead of `f.hidden_field`, the form is sending `:user_id`, instead of `[:cricket_club_advert][:user_id]`.

Just change:

```
 <%= hidden_field_tag "user_id", current_user_id %>
```

For:

```
 <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user_id %>
```

**RECOMENDATION (IMPORTANT)**

The way you are handling the value of `user_id` is opening a **vulnerability** on your app. If I manually change the value of that `hidden_input` from my browser I would be able to create a `cricket_club_advert` under the name of any other user of your app from my account.

**Example.** 
Lets say I'm the current_user and my `id` is `5` and there is another user with an `id` of `7`. If I manually change the value of your hidden_input from `5` (the current_user id), to `7` (the other user id), your app is going to create the `cricket_club_advert` for the other user I manually specified.

You should handdle the `user_id` value on your controller and not in your form. Like this:

```
# I assume an user has_many :cricket_club_adverts
def create
  cricket_club_advert = current_user.cricket_club_adverts.build(ricket_club_advert_params)
  if cricket_club_advert.save
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```

This way you ensure that an user can only create a `cricket_club_advert` under his name.